# Maintain one requirements.txt for a semi-private Python project with editable dependencies

Tags: python, pip

I have a Python package (A) that depends on another package (B). I am developing them locally at the same time. My `requirements.txt` for A looks like:

```
--editable /path/to/B
--editable .
```

I will be sharing both packages with others, but not listing them on PyPI. When I distribute A, users will need to obtain the dependency B. I can specify where to get B in a `requirements.txt`:

```
git+https://github.com/smackesey/B#egg=B
.
```

But this `requirements.txt` is different than the one I use locally. Is it possible to maintain one requirements.txt that satisfies both needs?